# Karma w/RequireJS gets 404 loading file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, karma-runner, centos7

I'm working with a build that has a working karma setup.

I'm trying to integrate require.js usage into the tests.  I mostly followed the instructions in the Karma RequireJS doc page to convert my "karma.conf.js" and build the "test-main.js".

When I run the tests, I see something like this:

```
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
...
    /home/<myuid>/work/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xstatic/pkg/angular/data/angular.js
...
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for .venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xstatic/pkg/angular/data/angular.js!'
...
WARN [web-server]: 404: /.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xstatic/pkg/angular/data/angular.js
DEBUG [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux)]: Disconnected during run, waiting 2000ms for reconnecting.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exited with code 1
ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS crashed.
```

I run Karma with:

```
node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start horizon/karma.conf.js --single-run
```

Note that the directory I run this from has the ".venv" folder and the file mentioned in the 404 does exist in that location.

Here is my "horizon/karma.conf.js" file:

```
module.exports = function(config){
  // Path to xstatic pkg path.
  var xstaticPath = '../../.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xstatic/pkg/';
  config.set({
preprocessors: {
  // Used to collect templates for preprocessing.
  // NOTE: the templates must also be listed in the files section below.
  './**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
  // Used to indicate files requiring coverage reports.
  './**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage']
},
// Sets up module to process templates.
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  prependPrefix: '/static/',
  moduleName: 'templates'
},
// Assumes you're in the top-level horizon directory.
basePath : './static/',
// Contains both source and test files.
files : [
    {pattern: xstaticPath + '**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: '../../test-shim.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'horizon/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'dashboard-app/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'framework/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: '**/*.spec.js', included: false},
    '../test-main.js'
],
autoWatch : true,
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
browsers : ['PhantomJS'],
phantomjsLauncher: {
  // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered
  // (useful if karma exits without killing phantom)
  exitOnResourceError: true
},
reporters : [ 'progress', 'coverage' ],
plugins : [
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-firefox-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-requirejs'
],
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
coverageReporter: {
  type : 'html',
  dir : '../.coverage-karma/'
}
  });
};
```

ere is my "horizon/test-main.js" (note that I tried to inline the variable reference value, which didn't help):

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /\.spec\.js$/;
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
    allTestFiles.push(file);
    }
  }
});
var xstaticPath = '../../.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xstatic/pkg/';
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base',
  paths: {
  'test-shim':         '../../test-shim',
  'jquery':            xstaticPath + 'jquery/data/jquery',
  //'angular':           xstaticPath + 'angular/data/angular',
  'angular':           '../../.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xstatic/pkg/angular/data/angular',
  'angular-mocks':     xstaticPath + 'angular/data/angular-mocks',
  'angular-cookies':   xstaticPath + 'angular/data/angular-cookies',
  'angular-bootstrap': xstaticPath + 'angular_bootstrap/data/angular-bootstrap',
  'angular-sanitize':  xstaticPath + 'angular/data/angular-sanitize',
  'd3':                xstaticPath + 'd3/data/d3',
  'rickshaw':          xstaticPath + 'rickshaw/data/rickshaw',
  'smart-table':       xstaticPath + 'angular_smart_table/data/smart-table',
  'lrdragndrop':       xstaticPath + 'angular_lrdragndrop/data/lrdragndrop',
  'spin':              xstaticPath + 'spin/data/spin',
  'spin-jquery':       xstaticPath + 'spin/data/spin.jquery',
  'magic-search':      xstaticPath + 'magic_search/data/magic_search'
  },
  shim: {
'underscore': {
  exports: '_'
}
  },
  deps: allTestFiles,
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Is there something obviously wrong, or is there something I can do to get more information?  I'm running this on CentOS 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `karma.conf.js` to this:

```
files : [
    // Must be before xstaticPath + '**/*.js' to be included
    '../test-main.js',
    {pattern: xstaticPath + '**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: '../../test-shim.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'horizon/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'dashboard-app/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'framework/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: '**/*.spec.js', included: false}

],
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Is the only change to move the "../test-main.js" reference to the top?  If so, the only change in the output was to change "There is no timestamp for .venv" to "There is no timestamp for /.venv". I didn't particular expect this to work, because an older app that I integrated karma/requirejs had the "test-main" reference last.

Comment: However, I then reverted the change, and it still says "/.venv", so I don't know why that happened.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should keep `test-main.js` on top if you use a pattern like `{pattern: '**/*.js', included: false}` because we ran into this use and we still have a comment for this. Anyway, we are missing something (else). I don't fully see your folders structure, are you sure about the `basePath : './static/',`? It clearly looks like a path issue.

Comment: Other ideas: you could turn the log level to `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,` to have a more verbose output to find out the bug. And could you try with another browser than PhantomJS too? I don't trust it anymore, we had too much strange behaviors with it. ;) Good luck!

Comment: It certainly needs to be above any "include: false" entries that would match the same pattern, but as you can see, none of those match that pattern. Yes, I'm pretty sure of that "basePath" value. This build with just karma was working fine. It only fails when I add requirejs. I didn't change the basePath value.

Comment: If you look in my console output above, you'll see the "DEBUG" lines, showing that I already did this.

Comment: You don't have another require config file in this project? You can look at [our angular/requirejs structure](https://github.com/glepretre/angular-requirejs-ready) maybe it will give you a clue. Sorry about the log level advice, I missed that out. Another stupid idea, maybe you've already thought about it but: you don't have any `/.venv/...angular` request in your app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79817/discussion-between-david-m-karr-and-glepretre).